# lowess fit curve in R

Tags: r, curve-fitting

This code gives me the mean, but I don't know how to get the +1sd and -1 sd lines.

```
y<-lowess(x[,1],x[,2],f=0.01)
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmm, perhabs msir:::loess.sd() does what you want:

```
require(graphics)
plot(cars, main = "lowess(cars)")

require(msir)
low <- loess.sd(cars[ ,1], cars[ ,2])
lines(low$x, low$y)
lines(low$x, low$upper)
lines(low$x, low$lower)
```

[image]